# Error trying to build function to show image coordinates in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use this code in a React component so I can build an image map.
console.log(document.getElementById("SS").clientHeight);

```
function showCoords(event)
{
    alert(event.pageX + " " + event.pageY);
}


return(
    <div>
    <img src={solarSystem} alt="Solar System" usemap="#SSMap" id = "SS" onClick={showCoords(event)} />
```

Yes, I have a component (image) with the id SS.  But when I try to start the React App I get this error:

```
Line 24:93:  Unexpected use of 'event'  no-restricted-globals
```

If I change it to "onClick = {(event) => showCoords(event)}, I get these errors:

```
    2bundle.js:41 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'clientHeight')
    at SS (bundle.js:41:44)
    at renderWithHooks (bundle.js:23664:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (bundle.js:27329:17)
    at beginWork (bundle.js:28797:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:11460:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:11509:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:11571:35)
    at beginWork$1 (bundle.js:34584:11)
    at performUnitOfWork (bundle.js:33717:16)
    at workLoopSync (bundle.js:33630:9)
bundle.js:26003 The above error occurred in the <SS> component:

    at SS (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41:44)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ bundle.js:26003
bundle.js:34066 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'clientHeight')
    at SS (bundle.js:41:44)
    at renderWithHooks (bundle.js:23664:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (bundle.js:27329:17)
    at beginWork (bundle.js:28797:20)
    at beginWork$1 (bundle.js:34559:18)
    at performUnitOfWork (bundle.js:33717:16)
    at workLoopSync (bundle.js:33630:9)
    at renderRootSync (bundle.js:33599:11)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (bundle.js:33007:24)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (bundle.js:32908:26)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const App = () => {
  const imgRef = React.useRef(null);
  function showCoords(event) {
      alert(event.pageX + " " + event.pageY);
      // console.log(document.getElementById('SS').clientHeight);
      console.log(imgRef.current.clientHeight);
  }


  return(
      <div>
        <img ref={imgRef} src={solarSystem} alt="Solar System" usemap="#SSMap" id = "SS" onClick={showCoords} />
      </div>
  )
}
```

You should use ref to get `clientHeight`.